# Theme in user control

Tags: c#, asp.net

How can I change `Page.Theme` dynamically in `UserControl`?

As far as I know it can be done in `Page_PreInit` but `UserControl` dont have such an event, it`s exists only in Page class.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MSDN [says](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms379601%28v=vs.80%29.aspx#themes_topic8):

> You must be aware of one restriction
>   when using the theme property. The
>   theme property can only be set during
>   or before the `Page` `PreInit` event.

The user control life cycle starts right after the page's `PreInit` event, so you won't be able to set the theme directly from your control.

But still there is a little workaround: assuming the current theme is stored in the session object, you could change this session value in any place of your user control, then just refresh the page e.g. by using `Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri)` and change the theme in the `Page_PreInit` handler:

Here is page's `PreInit` event handler:

```
protected void Page_PreInit(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var theme = Session["Theme"] as string;
    if (theme != null) 
    {
        Page.Theme = theme;
    }
}
```

and e.g. `OnSelectedIndexChanged` event handler in your user control:

```
protected void ddlTheme_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    Session["Theme"] = ddlTheme.SelectedValue;
    Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);
}
```

Comment: The `Response.Redirect(Request.Url.AbsoluteUri);` will give us an infinite loop. We need to check `if (Session["Theme"] != ddlTheme.SelectedValue)`

Comment: Yes, `Response.Redirect` will give you an infinite loop if you use it in a code which executes on every page processing. In the example above, it is assumed to be executed on a postback only. But yes, you're right that the value needs to be checked.

Answer (score 0):

On user control load event, use:

```
this.ApplyStyleSheetSkin(Page);
```

Comment: It`s not answered my question... I want to change the theme dynamically from OnLoad of the UserControl. `Page.Theme = "MyCustomTheme";`